# How can read changing data in methods after created with Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

My code like this:

```html
<tempalte>
  <div>{{contents}}</div>
</tempalte>
<script>
{
  //...something
  data: function() {
    return { contents: null }
  },
  methods: {
    test() {
      console.log(this.contents)  
    }
  },
  created () {
    // do something...
    this.contents = someValue
    this.test()
  }
}
</script>
```

And when `created` excuted then call test methods, the print result is old value `null`.
But the `{{contents}}` is the new Value.

How can I get new value of data in methods after created assign new value and call the methods ?

---

I has already fixed it. If I call methods in updated (), it can work.

If you want to know the reasons, you can read this post:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

Comment: Check out this jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/upo7fof3/7/), it seems to be working fine. Can you show more code in your snippet?

Comment: Show what "do something" in `created () {` is.

Comment: @acdcjunior Use AWS SDK to get data from S3.

Comment: There you go, your code is asynchronous.

Comment: Thanks, I has already fixed it. <3